# How to use two controllers for a single template in AngularJS stateprovider for routing?

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

Here i am using state provider,for routing.I want to use two controllers for a single template,how to write the syntax?

This is what i tried.

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'
  controller: 'Searchresults'
});

 $stateProvider.state("home", {
  url: "/",
  controller: ['HomeController','Searchresults']
});
```

Comment: What is the purpose of two controllers? Can you have a factory do the work that you have split in two controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this doesn't sounds good that you want to use two controllers for the same template. Why can't you just use the same controller or the services to keep the logic common?

Apart from the recommendation, you can try this. Add your first controller to state configuration:

```
$stateProvider.state("home", {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  controller: 'HomeController'    // 1st controller here
});
```

And add the second controller as `ng-controller` in the parent element of the `home.html`:

```
<div ng-controller="Searchresults">
   <!-- your code of home.html -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou #Shashank. A small doubt ,where to write the searchresults controller?Will it tale automatically in routing